# Why does this wordpress site redirect wrongly in Chrome?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Google has indexed this page http://[site-removed]/showering-accessories on my client's site which doesn't actually exist. The correct URL should be http://[site-removed]/products-page/showering-accessories

I don't want the site to be penalised in Google, So I've added this rule in .htaccess in the root of the site:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/showering-accessories /products-page/showering-accessories
```

(Note: I had been experimenting with 301 redirects previously)

This works as intended in IE and Firefox, but in Chrome I end up at this page, due to what I assume is a wordpress application-level (PHP) redirect:

```
http://[site-removed]/products-page/products
```

Why is this? Shouldn't the .htaccess rules always kick in before it reaches the PHP code?
How can I fix it?

BTW I also have these rules below the RedirectMatch:

```
# Redirect all pages to subdirectory /new
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /new/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That redirect works fine for me when I use chrome. Are you sure your Chrome doesn't have an old redirect cached or something?

Comment: @JonLin Hey you're right, all the links work great if I open them from an incognito tab in Chrome! Add this as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That redirect works fine for me when I use chrome. Are you sure your Chrome doesn't have an old redirect cached or something?

Comment: i've had that problem so many times. try it in incognito mode (with no other open incognito windows), thats always a good way to test it